# Rails 3 Authlogic Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

What are some good rails 3 tutorials for implementing Authlogic? The example listed on github is quite outdated and while the Railscast example does a great job of explaining everything it is beginning to show its age.

Comment: Check this out: http://joelgreutman.com/2011/03/13/rails-3-and-authlogic-basic-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard mixed reviews about devise but after installing it, watching several railscasts on its capabilities, and going through the tutorials I've decided to stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try devise, its a lot simpler :)

Comment: @Frazley I was considering Devise but don't know too much about it, will have to check it out though!